# Getting radioGroup selected value

Tags: listener, gxt, radio-group

I am trying to get the selected radio's value. I'm using gxt's RadioGroup for that. Here's the code snippet:

final RadioGroup `radioGroup = new RadioGroup("RadioGroup")`

(some code which adds radios to RadioGroup)

```
radioGroup.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener(){ 
  public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be){ 
     selectedRadio = radioIDList.get(radioOptionValue.indexOf(*radioGroup.getValue()*));  
     System.out.println("selectedRadio: "+selectedRadio); 
  } 
 });
```

My problem is that it cannot find radioGroup inside handleEvent. It says ..'cannot be resolved;. If I could only execute `radioGroup.getValue()` my problem would be solved. 
I looked up on google and found out that people have used BaseEvent, FieldEvent instead of `radioGroup.getValue()`, neither of which is working.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting. I'm new to using online forums

Comment: You can edit your question and add some code fragments. Select code and then use Ctrl+k :)

Comment: Thanks for your help with the formatting guys. I din't check this post for a long time since I used other approach to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

try to use:

```
radioGroup.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener(){ 
  public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be){ 
     RadioGroup caller = (RadioGroup)be.getSource();
  } 
 });
```